# Salesforce employee licence

Tags: community

Can any one help me to know about employee community licenses and feature and can I read opportunity and lead object with this community license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leads and Opportunities are not in. The objects you can access in Eployee portal:

- Accounts (read-only)
- Contacts (read-only)
- Salesforce Knowledge (read-only)
- Cases (create, read, comment only)
- 10 custom objects
- Tasks and Events